# Launch Spark-Submit with restful service in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

following [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask) tutorial I've made a restful service in python.
Using this service I want to call an other python script with `spark-submit`, but it doens't work.

Here my **service.py**:

```
import pickle
import subprocess
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from json import dumps
from flask_jsonpify import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Test(Resource):
    def post(self):
        imageID = request.form.get('imageID')
        tags = request.form.get('tags')

        return subprocess.call("spark-submit NaiveBayesClassifier.py",shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)


api.add_resource(Test, '/test') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5002)
```

This service is made with virtualenv started using this:

```
source venv/bin/activate
python service.py
```

But when the script run `ubprocess.call("spark-submit NaiveBayesClassifier.py",shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` it return me this error:

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5002/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Insufficient space for shared memory 
file:
   34475
 Try using the -Djava.io.tmpdir= option to select an alternate temp location.

 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Insufficient space for shared memory file:
   34462
Try using the -Djava.io.tmpdir= option to select an alternate temp location.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usertest/project/NaiveBayesClassifier.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2018 14:36:06] "POST /test HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Any ideas about the problem? I'm using Spark 1.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three problems.

**First** in your code, you should use Popen in this way:

```
class Test(Resource):
    def post(self):
        imageID = request.form.get('imageID')
        tags = request.form.get('tags')

        p = subprocess.Popen(["spark-submit", "NaiveBayesClassifier.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        return p.communicate()
```

**Second** in your virtualenv you should install *pip*

```
pip install numpy
```

or using sudo if you get an errors

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

**Third** this message means that there's no more space in your HDD. Try to delete some large file or incrase your partition if you can.

```
warning: Insufficient space for shared memory file: 34475
```